# Como Añadir Elementos (filas) a una tabla desde jQuery, Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, tablas

intento crear para uso personal, un sistema para crear presupuestos:

tengo la siguiente estructura:

1. Este `DIV`: Me muestra un listado de servicios desde ajax, además, tiene un buscador en ajax para encontrar el servicio o producto.

> ```
> <div id="resultadosPresupuestos"> 
> </div>
> ```

[image: Buscador Ajax y PHP]

Justo debajo, tengo una tabla, en la que se supone, que al darle al `+` debería añadir el servicio a la tabla.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora, y no me funciona:

Ajax:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addLane', function () {

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(id);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/addLinea.php',
      data: {'id': id}
    })
    .done(function(listas_rep){
      $('#tablaDatosPresu').append(listas_rep)
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('Hubo un errror al añadir la línea al presupuesto')
    })

});
```

La clase addLane, la estoy sacando de PHP, de la celda `+`, contiene la ID del artículo, que la paso por ajax al siguiente PHP:

```
function setLinea(){
  $mysqli = getConn();
  $codigo = $_POST['id'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `servicios` WHERE codigo = $codigo";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);

  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $indices = '<tr>
                    <td>' .$row[codigo]. '</td>
                    <td>' .$row[nombre]. '</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>' .$row[precio]. '</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>' .$row[iva]. '</td>
                    <td>total</td>
                    <td>trash</td>
                </tr>';
  }

  return $indices;
}

echo setLinea();
```

La tabla, en la que añadir las líneas, sería la siguiente, (se encuentra dentro de un `div`):

```
<div id="datosPresupuesto">
    <br>
    <table id="tablaDatosPresu">
        <tr>
            <th>Codigo</th>
            <th width="320px;">Descripción</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Dto %</th>
            <th>IVA</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td width="320px;"><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="21%"></td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Por cada vez que se inserta una línea, se debería crear un:**

```
<tr>
   <td>
   <td>
   <td>
   <td>
   <td>
   <td>
   <td>
   <td>
</tr>
```

Al pinchar en el `+` para añadir, en este momento, el ajax me sale por el 'fail'.

Agradecería ayuda, para ver como podría solventar este problema. Y lograr hacerlo funcionar.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si retornas el error en el `fail` y lo agregas a tu pregunta podríamos ayudarte mas, probaste agregando comillas, por ejemplo `$row["codigo"]`

Comment: No sería necesario añadir las comillas dobles, ¿Como podría imprimir el error?

Comment: Pues, me está devolviendo entre otras cosas un texto de  "Internal Server Error"

Comment: No consigo encontrar ni el error ni la solución :/

Comment: usa `.fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log(textStatus);
    alert('Hubo un errror al añadir la línea al presupuesto')
})`

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8888/seoagency/php/addLinea.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ presupuestos.js:32
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
presupuestos.js:41 error  -> Eso es lo que me devuelve :/

Comment: Prueba pasar los parámetros de esta forma `data: 'id='+id`

Comment: Nada, continúa este error: jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8888/../php/addLinea.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82723/discussion-between-kevin-and-javier-avila-fernandez).

Comment: Me ha desaparecido el chat.

Comment: define la variable `$indices` antes del `while` y si pasa por `done` es la consulta la que no esta retornando los datos